# create a popup with a db-generated select list to add an item to a linked select

Tags: php, jquery

first i apologise for my poor english.
My problem : I have two linked select's  who work perfectly :
- a list of hospitals
- a list of services depending of the choice of one hospital.
 I would like to add a button after the second list to add a service coming from the whole list of services.

html generated by php code : fiche_action.php

```
   print '<tr><td class="titre" width="20%" nowrap="nowrap">'.$langs->trans("Etablissement").'</b></td><td>';
   print '<select class="flat"  STYLE="width:300px" id="hopital" name="hopital">';
   print '<option value="">---Hopital---</option>';
   print '</select>';
   print '</td></tr>';

   print '<tr><td class="titre" width="20%" nowrap="nowrap">'.$langs->trans("Service").'</b></td><td>';
   print '<select class="flat"  STYLE="width:300px" id="service" name="service">';
   print '<option value="">---Services---</option>';
   print '</select>';
   print '<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="bttn_add" name="bttn_add">';
   print img_picto($langs->trans("Ajouter service"),"blue_plus_bis.png");
   print '</a>';
   print '</td>';
   print '</tr>';
```

Le jquery : listd_xhr.js

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(
    function( $ ) 
{
    var $hopital = $('#hopital');
    var $service = $('#service');
    var $btton_add = $('#btton_add');

// chargement des hopitaux
$.ajax 
({
    url: 'hospi_service.php',
    data: 'go', // on envoie $_GET['go']
    dataType: 'json', // on veut un retour JSON
    success: function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(index, value) { // pour chaque noeud JSON
            // on ajoute l option dans la liste
            $hopital.append('<option value="'+ index +'">'+ value +'</option>');
        });
    }
});

// à la sélection d un hopital dans la liste
$hopital.on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val(); // on récupère la valeur de l'hosto

    if(val != '') {
        $service.empty(); // on vide la liste des services

        $.ajax({
            url: 'hospi_service.php',
            data: 'id_hopital='+ val, // on envoie $_GET['id_hopital']
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                $.each(json, function(index, value) {
                    $service.append('<option value="'+ index +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

// au click sur le bouton
$btton_add.on('click',function(){
    // a popup displayed with select new_service
    // 
    // Insert in the bdd the link hopital - new_service
    // 
    // Back to services list

});


});
```

Le traitement php : hospi_services.php

```
<?php

require("pre.inc.php");

if(isset($_GET['go']) || isset($_GET['id_hopital'])) {

$json = array();

if(isset($_GET['go'])) {
    // requête qui récupère les hopitaux
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT o.id , o.nom";
$sql.= " FROM ".MAIN_DB_PREFIX ."organisation as o";
$sql.= " WHERE (o.fk_type=15  OR o.fk_type=108 or o.fk_type=131)";
$sql.= " AND o.fk_uo=".$user->fk_uo;
$sql.= " ORDER BY nom ASC";

} elseif(isset($_GET['id_hopital'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id_hopital'];
    // requête qui récupère les services selon la région
     $sql = "SELECT sc.libelle as nom, sc.id";
     $sql .= " FROM ".MAIN_DB_PREFIX ."c_specialite AS sc";
     $sql .= " LEFT JOIN ".MAIN_DB_PREFIX ."service_org AS so ON so.fk_service = sc.id";
     $sql .= " WHERE so.fk_organisation =".$id;
     $sql .= " ORDER BY sc.libelle ASC";
}

 $resql = $db->query($sql);
 $num = $db->num_rows($resql);
 $i = 0;
    if ($num){
   while ($i < $num){
        $obj = $db->fetch_object($resql);
        $json[$obj->id][] = $obj->nom;
        $i++;
       }
    }


// envoi du résultat au success
echo json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

Any help welcome...

Answer (score 0):

i finally succeded by reading similar topics. Jquery-ui "dialog" is my friend.

So, i'd like to mark my question as "solved".